# Dropdown icon in <select> went missing when I add border-style: none

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem, I am using firefox browser and I have this simple line of html codes:

```css
    .list {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2.5% 0;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.list-select, .list-submit {
 width: 95%;
 margin: 0 2.5%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 border-width: .1em;
}

.list-select select {
 border-style: none;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
   <form method="post">
      <div class="list-select">
      <select>
      <option>Test</option>
   </select>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="token_home" value="token_value">
   <div class="list-submit">
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
   </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

When I added the `border-style: none;` the dropdown icon disappears along with `border-style`. Is this a natural? If so, how can I fix this? I need to remove the `border-style` but I do not want to disappear the dropdown icon.

Comment: i can see the dropdown in the snippet, which browser show issue /

Comment: Yeah, the dropdown is visible. It's probably a browser issue, or some other style in your CSS is affecting it.

Comment: The dropdown-arrow is there, so I don't understand your issue. And yes, I'm using Firefox.

Comment: I update the snippet with my code, unfortunately, here it works but in my localhost it isn't. :(

Comment: I think other style is affecting it, gonna find it!

Comment: Why it works on google chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! The answer is there is a **bug** in mozilla firefox, my problem occurs when I tried my code in **Responsive Design Mode** and when I return it to normal view the drop down icon is there. Hope Mozilla fix this small problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
  border-width: 0px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  display: block;
}
```

border-width: 0px;<-- use this

It works, for me, on Firefox and others browser!

Comment: Tried it and I failed.

Answer (score 0):

If is disappearing also in other browsers not only in firefox could be that your background color of dropdown icon is same than main background color. Maybe is still there and is just invisible. Or your class or id of icons is "border-style"- higly unlikely.